# How to test and run games using Unreal Engine 4 (ETC2 texture format) in Android Studio emulated devices?

Tags: android, android-studio

It seems that none of the emulated devices provided by Android Studio supports ETC2 texture format. I've tried Android 12, Android 12L and Android T Beta in Android Studio but on all virtual devices I always get the same error:

```
Unsupported Texture Format
Cooked Flavors: ETC2
Supported: ETC1,ASTC
```

Is there any way to enable ETC2 on the Emulators? I want to run the app on the newest APIs so  I prefer Android Studio over Android-x86, GenyMotion or BlueStacks because the latter mostly still only support old distros.

Comment: What mode have you configured for the emulator? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration What 3D hardware is available in the host system?

Comment: The emulator's GPU mode is set as "auto". My main PC is running WSL2 as well so it has Hyper-V enabled, so the emulator must be using Hyper-V's hardware acceleration. Also my PC has an AMD chip.